# If I change the DE on Ubuntu will my files be deleted?

Tags: unity, 14.04, xfce

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity and I'd like to switch the desktop environment to Xfce instead of Unity. I was wondering if my files (pictures, music, pdfs) will switch over or would they be deleted?

I'm using [this guide](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative) to switch from Unity to Xfce.

Comment: That link suggests two different ways of installing the Xfce desktop.  If you do a fresh install of Xubuntu you will a cleaner system but may lose all your personal files so back up first.  If you just install the Xfce desktop along side Unity with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop gksu leafpad synaptic` your data will be safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your files in the home directory will be untouched, and available from the new GUI. No need to worry. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry @LuísdeSousa, but I don't understand what you mean. The OP asked if his files will be preserved, and I told him they will.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, a desktop environment is a piece of software that you install on your system. It is like any other programme, but with the broad task of providing you with a visual environment to manage running programmes and the file system.

Thus, the result of installing Xubuntu from the Software Centre or Synpatic is *simply* the addition of a large set of libraries, programmes and configurations to your system. These will usually go into places such as `/usr/bin` and `/usr/share`. No files are deleted in the process and the operating system (Linux kernel) is left untouched. Your `home` folder is also left untouched, as well as any personal configurations you may have stored there.

And the most beautiful thing of all is that Unity will remain installed and you may (at log in time) choose which desktop environment to use in that session.

Answer (score 1):

Installing additional desktop enviroments such as Xubuntu or Lubuntu won't touch your personal files. In most cases files will remain untouched, especially if they are in your home directory.

The only time you would lose all your files is if you was to install a new version of Linux (Xubuntu, etc.) over your old partition from a Live CD.